# Button Takes Up My Whole Screen

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout-manager

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class box{
    public static String b1state = "A";
    public static String b2state = "S";
    public static String b3state = "D";
    public static String b4state = "F";
    public static String b5state = "G";
    public static String b6state = "H";
    public static String b7state = "J";
    public static String b8state = "K";
    public static String b9state = "Q";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        JButton b1 = new JButton(b1state);
        b1.setLocation(100,  50);
        JButton b2 = new JButton(b2state);
        b2.setLocation(150, 50);
        JButton b3 = new JButton(b3state);
        b3.setLocation(200, 50);
        JButton b4 = new JButton(b4state);
        b4.setLocation(100, 100);
        JButton b5 = new JButton(b5state);
        b5.setLocation(150, 100);
        JButton b6 = new JButton(b6state);
        b6.setLocation(200, 100);
        JButton b7 = new JButton(b7state);
        b7.setLocation(100, 150);
        JButton b8 = new JButton(b8state);
        b8.setLocation(150, 150);
        JButton b9 = new JButton(b9state);
        b9.setLocation(200, 150);

        b1.setSize(50, 50);
        b2.setSize(50, 50);
        b3.setSize(50, 50);
        b4.setSize(50, 50);
        b5.setSize(50, 50);
        b6.setSize(50, 50);
        b7.setSize(50, 50);
        b8.setSize(50, 50);
        b9.setSize(50, 50);

        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(b3);
        p.add(b4);
        p.add(b5);
        p.add(b6);
        p.add(b7);
        p.add(b8);
        p.add(b9);

        frame.add(p);
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);
        frame.add(b3);
        frame.add(b4);
        frame.add(b5);
        frame.add(b6);
        frame.add(b7);
        frame.add(b8);
        frame.add(b9);
    }
```

When ever I run this sometimes it works but other times it just opens the window with a whole button taking up the screen! Please Help!

Comment: Learn about how the Swing layout managers work and you'll see why your button fills the screen. To get the link, hover over the swing tag I've added to your question and click on "info" and then the layout manager tutorial. Note that JFrame contentPanes use BorderLayout. You may want to read on GridLayout, and you may wish to get rid of those useless calls to `setLocation(...)`. They're not going to help you, and right now are only fooling you into thinking that they're doing something when they're not, and are not even needed.

Comment: Your link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: Other suggestions going forward -- don't setSize or setBounds either. Let the components and the layout managers set the sizes. Avoid putting the whole GUI together in the static main method. That method should be just for creating an object and starting it up, and that's about it, and this should take just a few lines of code. Also you'll want to learn and follow Java naming rules, including giving classes names that begin with a capital letter. This way others will more easily understand your code.

Comment: BTW - the code example probably would have failed with just 2 buttons, so there's no need for the other seven.

Comment: You have taken a `JPanel` __p__ in this case, and added all `JButton`s to it, now it's time to add this `JPanel` to some container. But you starting adding those `JButton`s again to some other place. Just try this, take a `JPanel`. Change it's layout to `GridLayout` by `p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5))`, now add all `JButton`s to it, like `p.add(b1)` and so on. Now add this `JPanel` to `JFrame` by `frame.setContentPane(p)`, now call `pack()`, and then call `frame.setVisible(true)`. Do not call `setVisible()` before adding needed components to the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A component may only reside within a single parent, adding a component to another container will remove it from the first, so basically, nothing resides within your `JPanel` anymore...
2. `JFrame` by default, uses a `BorderLayout`, which means that only one component can occupy any of the five available spaces it provides.  What's happening with your code is `b9`, been the last component added to your frame, is the only component been displayed.  `BorderLayout` is providing `b9` with the full available space to it.

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  You may need to use multiple layouts in order to achieve what you want, but this allows you to separate responsibility and isolate the individual requirements of each section of your interface

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
```

with:

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
```

And this:

```
    frame.add(p);
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.add(b2);
    frame.add(b3);
    frame.add(b4);
    frame.add(b5);
    frame.add(b6);
    frame.add(b7);
    frame.add(b8);
    frame.add(b9);
```

with this:

```
    frame.setContentPane(p);
```

---

This will make your code "work".
But you have to play more with the containers to learn how to "layout" components. I suggest you this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1):

i had a problem just like that if its the last button that fill your window you can "cheat" by adding another button at the end of your code and then disable him and make him invisible like this.
`cheater.setVisible(false);
 cheater.setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score -1):

you can also fix this by setting your layout to null so panel.setLayout(null);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).